# Pass file name having space to update operation using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, updatelistitems

I am using on premise SharePoint server 2016.I am using rest api to update a list.I have a list having space in it's name so while passing this name it causes problem.Is it possible to pass file name having space to update operation.
Suppose list name is 'abc list'.

```
 $.ajax  
    ({  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('abc%20list')/items("+Idtoupdate+")", // list item ID  
        type: "POST",  
        data: JSON.stringify  
        ({  
            __metadata:  
            {  
                type: "SP.Data.abc%20list"  
            },  
            Uploaded:value

        }),  
        headers:  
        {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
            "IF-MATCH": "*",  
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"  
        },  
async: false,  
        success: function(data, status, xhr)  
        {  
            debugger;
        },  
        error: function(xhr, status, error)  
        {  
            debugger;
        }  
    });
```

I am getting error at json.strignify.

Error:

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"A type named 'SP.Data.Approver DashboardListItem' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type.\"}}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A type named 'SP.Data.Approver DashboardListItem' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type."}}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}

Comment: Can you please post the error you are getting?

Comment: posted an error

Comment: This is the same problem as I mentioned in my answer. Hit this URL in browser : `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listName')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName` to check the `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` for your list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the display name of your SharePoint List in REST API call like below:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('abc list')/items"
```

Also make sure you are passing correct `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` in `type` property inside `__metadata`.

You can check `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` of your list using below URL:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listName')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

Common Format of `ListItemEntityTypeFullName`:

```
SP.Data.ListNameListItem
```

Replace **only** `ListName` with your list name.

**Update**:

For your case try using below:

```
data: JSON.stringify  
    ({  
        __metadata:  
        {  
            type: "SP.Data.Approver_x0020_DashboardListItem"  
        },  
        Uploaded:value

    })
```

Generally in `ListItemEntityTypeFullName`, Space is replaced by `_x0020_`. But, it is always recommended to check `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` of your list by using:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listName')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

Comment: Resoved by getting ListItemEntityTypeFullName using /_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listName')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName