# Update URL alternative text from PowerAutomate within link list. Error message concerning type

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, url, power-automate, links-list

I want to update items in a link list. Part of is automatic generation of an URL. That URL should provide an alternative text. So I know, I have to formulate an http request instead of the update item action.

I read through different websites and followed the instruction here:

[Update hyperlink column on tachytelic.net](https://www.tachytelic.net/2021/03/update-hyperlink-column-sharepoint-power-automate/)

List name is "DCDC-RMTick".

I formulated a POST request:

```
{
   "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Data.DCDC-RMTickListItem"
   },
   "URL": {
       "Description": "#0000",
       "Url": "https://smt-redmine.mycompany.com/redmine/issues/0000"
   }
}
```

I get an error (unfortunately for you in German) complaining that the type could not be resolved by the model (if I translated it correctly).

The error code:

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Ein Typ mit dem Namen \"SP.Data.DCDC-RMTickListItem\" konnte vom Modell nicht aufgelöst 
              werden. Wenn ein Modell verfügbar ist, muss jeder Typname in einen gültigen Typ aufgelöst werden können.\r\nclientRequestId: b6ec4ad8-7a0d-48a5-890a-2b001a76e34f\r\nserviceRequestId: 0f1fc79f-d067-c000-0106-3de89df59262",
  "source": "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/O3.33400Illu/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('DCDC-RMTick')/items(19)",
  "errors": [
              "-1",
              "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
            ]
}
```

For the sake of completeness some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Do I have to supply a different content type than "ListItem"?

The content type of the URL list is "Verknüpfung" (probably link in English), which is the standard for link lists in SP. Or is there something different I have botched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are passing correct `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` in `type` property inside `__metadata`.

You can check `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` of your list using below URL:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listName')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

Common Format of `ListItemEntityTypeFullName`:

```
SP.Data.ListNameListItem
```

Replace only `ListName` with your list name.

For more information, check: [Pass file name having space to update operation using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/267243/pass-file-name-having-space-to-update-operation-using-rest-api/267244#267244)

**Update from comments**:

You need to pass the URL in below format with the site URL (check below image):

[image]

And you need to use the highlighted value in `type` property. In my case, it is `SP.Data.Test_x005f_ListListItem`.

Comment: If I enter the URL in browser I get <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="de-DE">Der Ausdruck "web/lists/GetByTitle('DCDC-RMTick')/SP.Data.DCDC-RMTickListItem" ist ungültig.</m:message>
</m:error>

Comment: Do I have to supply the full path to the list in that URL? I used only the site as URL before /_api...

Comment: Sorry, I was too stupid to read and understand your post at first glance. I think I have to omit the dash. I'm reporting back as soon as I have tested.

Comment: Yes, you need to enter the URL in this format: `https://<your-tenant-name>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-name>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<list-name>')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName`. Check updated answer for more information.