# A type named ... could not be resolved by the model - but code is fine

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, error

I am trying to add an item to a SharePoint list synchronously. but I get the error

> "A type named 'SP.Data.QAReadAndSignListItem' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type."

I found this error a few times in google search, most of the solutions are in Power Automate, the other do not help me.

below is the code I am using:

```
$.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('QAReadAndSign')/items",
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "POST",
                "IF-MATCH": "*",

            },
            data: JSON.stringify
                ({
                    __metadata:
                    {
                        type: "SP.Data.QAReadAndSignListItem"
                    },
                    Title: "New Title"
                }),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Item updated successfully');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

What's wrong in my code? please help me, I am going to give up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using incorrect metadata type (`SP.Data.QAReadAndSignListItem`) in request body.

Try opening URL like below in browser tab to see the correct `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` of your list:

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('QAReadAndSign')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

**For example**:

[image]

Use the response of above URL in your request body.

**Reference**: [Pass file name having space to update operation using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/267243/pass-file-name-having-space-to-update-operation-using-rest-api/267244#267244)

Comment: Wow! you must be genius! It really worked!